# Jpa @CollectionTable very slow query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "GEO_MUNICIPALITY", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "idx_municipalityentity", columnList = "PROVINCE_CODE")
})
...
public class MunicipalityEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MUNICIPALITY_CODE", nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROVINCE_CODE")
    private ProvinceEntity province;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "GEO_MUNICIPALITY_POSTAL_CODE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MUNICIPALITY_CODE"),
    indexes = {
            @Index(name = "idx_municipalityentity_postal_code", columnList = "MUNICIPALITY_CODE")
    })
    @Column(name = "POSTAL_CODE")
    private List<String> postalCodeList;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "GEO_PROVINCE")
...
public class ProvinceEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String code;
...
}
```

Now my apis need to display all municipalities (with all municipality postal codes) with a given province code, so i have a repository class like this:

```java
@Repository
public interface MunicipalityJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<MunicipalityEntity, String> {
    List<MunicipalityEntity> findAllByProvinceCode(String province);

    @Query("select m from MunicipalityEntity m left join m.postalCodeList postalCodeList where m.province.code = ?1")
    List<MunicipalityEntity> findByCode(String code);
}
```

The two methods do the same thing and I tried in both way (an the result is the same) because when i call `getPostalCodeList()` the query is very slow because it make a select for every result of municipality (to retrive the postal codes).

How can I improve the performances?
Also, since I always search municipalities by code, is a good idea to make the index like in the code?
Thank you!

I tried both using jpa repository and custom query.
I was expecting a fast query execution time but the execution is very slow because after the join query the application make a query for each resulted municipality, to fetch the postal codes.

Comment: "_is very slow because after the join query the application make a query for each resulted municipality, to fetch the postal codes_", and it does because you invite it to do so, asking it to consider a `m.province.code` field. You're tricked, and I see a way, maybe to help you: add a `private String provinceCode` to the `MunicipalityEntity`. You will have to fill it at loading, and it will duplicate the province code, but it will avoid to load the whole province each time when you do not want to, by querying this new field only.

Comment: The custom query is performing a join, but not actually doing anything with it. Did you mean to maybe try a fetch join? "select m from MunicipalityEntity m left join fetch m.postalCodeList postalCodeList where m.province.code = ?1". This will prefetch the lists in 1 query instead of N+1 as you touch each MunicipalityEntity. You might also try using a batch query for the postalCodeList - try adding the @BatchSize annotation on the mapping to see if that helps instead of forcing a fetch join.

Answer (score 0):

A `left join` is not a `left join fetch` in JPQL. If I run your example and try to print the result I get the dreaded `LazyInitializationException`. You have said that you get a separate query for the PostalCodes but that is because you are accessing the postal codes while still in `Session`. This is something you should setup better in your application. I am no longer in session with my simple version of your example when I try to access the postal codes and so I get the `LazyInitializationException`.

With your original query:

```
@Query("from MunicipalityEntity m left join m.postalCodeList postalCodeList where m.province.code = ?1")
```

I get this SQL

```
Hibernate: select m1_0.municipality_code,m1_0.name,m1_0.province_code from geo_municipality m1_0 left join geo_municipality_postal_code p1_0 on m1_0.municipality_code=p1_0.municipality_code where m1_0.province_code=?
```

If I run that SQL in H2-CONSOLE I get

[image]

This is messed up because the sql result in a CARTESIAN PRODUCT but it is not including the POSTAL_CODE property. So if I fix the query to

```
@Query("from MunicipalityEntity m left join fetch m.postalCodeList postalCodeList where m.province.code = ?1")
```

I get the correct result

```
Hibernate: select m1_0.municipality_code,m1_0.name,p1_0.municipality_code,p1_0.postal_code,m1_0.province_code from geo_municipality m1_0 left join geo_municipality_postal_code p1_0 on m1_0.municipality_code=p1_0.municipality_code where m1_0.province_code=?
[MunicipalityEntity(code=MC1, name=MN1, postalCodeList=[PC1, PC2, PC3]), MunicipalityEntity(code=MC2, name=MN2, postalCodeList=[PC4, PC5, PC6]), MunicipalityEntity(code=MC3, name=MN3, postalCodeList=[PC7, PC8, PC9])]
```

as shown in the actual SQL

[image]

Note that is seems to require a `@Query` to address the issue. In JPA you can/should use EntityGraphs to tell JPA to fetch attributes you want that would not be normally fetched such as the postalCodeList.

So you can fix your regular SpringDataJpa method with a JPA `EntityGraph`. Without it I get.

```
Hibernate: select m1_0.municipality_code,m1_0.name,m1_0.province_code from geo_municipality m1_0 where m1_0.province_code=?
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.jpaplay.MunicipalityEntity.postalCodeList: could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:631) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:611) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:584) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
```

If I change it to

```
@EntityGraph(value = "MunicipalityEntity.postalCodeList",attributePaths = {"postalCodeList"}, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
List<MunicipalityEntity> findAllByProvinceCode(String province);
```

then I get what you want in the sql

```
Hibernate: select m1_0.municipality_code,m1_0.name,p2_0.municipality_code,p2_0.postal_code,m1_0.province_code from geo_municipality m1_0 left join geo_municipality_postal_code p2_0 on m1_0.municipality_code=p2_0.municipality_code where m1_0.province_code=?
[MunicipalityEntity(code=MC1, name=MN1, postalCodeList=[PC1, PC2, PC3]), MunicipalityEntity(code=MC2, name=MN2, postalCodeList=[PC4, PC5, PC6]), MunicipalityEntity(code=MC3, name=MN3, postalCodeList=[PC7, PC8, PC9])]
```

Also note that I am specifically not printing out the PROVINCE_CODE. If I do it will result in a `LazyInitializationException` as well.

```
    List<MunicipalityEntity> r = playService.query2();
    System.out.println(r);
    System.out.println(r.get(0).getProvince());
```

gives me

```
Hibernate: select m1_0.municipality_code,m1_0.name,p2_0.municipality_code,p2_0.postal_code,m1_0.province_code from geo_municipality m1_0 left join geo_municipality_postal_code p2_0 on m1_0.municipality_code=p2_0.municipality_code where m1_0.province_code=?
[MunicipalityEntity(code=MC1, name=MN1, postalCodeList=[PC1, PC2, PC3]), MunicipalityEntity(code=MC2, name=MN2, postalCodeList=[PC4, PC5, PC6]), MunicipalityEntity(code=MC3, name=MN3, postalCodeList=[PC7, PC8, PC9])]
....
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.example.jpaplay.ProvinceEntity#PC1] - no Session
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
```

I say you should handle your `Session` better in your application because if you access the PROVINCE_CODE after the initial query it will also result in another query. If you ensure your sessions are only active during your intended JPA access then you will get a `LazyInitializationException` instead of poor performance. Hope this helps. Always check the SQL queries generated by JPA to make sure you know what is going on.

PS> You might ask why a `LazyInitializationException` for `ProvinceEntity` when the query returns the PROVINCE_CODE. What about this?

```
System.out.println(r.get(0).getProvince().getCode());
```

Hope this helps.